# Under which account are startup and shutdown scripts executed on Windows 7 & XP?

Tags: windows, permissions

I'm trying to manually install and register xvid.ax and related DLLs on a bunch of Windows 7 and XP machines, which involves copying them to %windir%\system32. My attempts to effect this from startup scripts and powershell/win32_process have been ineffective, and I'm guessing it's a permissions problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Startup and shutdown scripts run under the `LocalSystem` built-in account (also commonly known as `System`), while logon and logoff scripts run in the context of the user account which is logging on/off.

If you are trying to copy those files from some network share, make sure the *computer* account of the affected system (or the `Domain Computers` domain group) has read access to it.

Answer (score 2):

Startup scripts run under the SYSTEM-Account. Have you checked the permissions of your shared folder?